# How to send XPM preview-session-token cookie to Session Content Service?

Tags: experience-manager, web8

My environment is Web8, DD4T 2 .net, REST CIL providers, Session-Enabled Content Service, Session Preview Service.

XPM in-line markup & editing works. XPM starts and works as expected, except the Update Preview functionality.

When clicking Update Preview, a cookie called `preview-session-token` is set on the page being edited and the page is reloaded.

At this moment, it seems this cookie is not picked up by the CIL providers (nor by the OData client) when it makes its request to the Session Content Service. As such, the Session Content Service doesn't know to retrieve 'preview' content and it simply returns 'published' content. The Update Preview therefore is not functioning.

I have traced the calls to the Session Content Service, but they don't seem to contain any `preview-session-token` cookie/header:

```
2016-10-16 21:50:57 TRACE [System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.FireSendingRequest2]
    OData V2 Service Request: http://staging-server:8081/client/v2/content.svc/PageContents(PageId=2593,PublicationId=9)?$top=1 (GET)
    DataServiceVersion:1.0;NetFx
    MaxDataServiceVersion:2.0;NetFx
    Accept:application/atom+xml,application/xml
    Accept-Charset:UTF-8
    User-Agent:Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
    authorization:Bearer cli...
```

My question is -- how to pass the session preview cookie to the Session Content Service?

I am not using any Tridion modules in the website (thus no ADF either).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ADF is required for XPM Session Preview. You will also have to configure the XPM Session Token as forwarded claim in `cd_ambient_conf.xml`.

Comment: How do you do that? Can you share a configuration sample please?